# Comparing String if( "bonaparte"=="bonaparte" ) this gives true result?

Tags: c, string, compare

**Note**: I know I can do this stuff by using `strcmp()` but I am just trying the equal to `==` operator.

**Code 1:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[]="bonaparte",s2[]="bonaparte";
    
    if(s1==s2)
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Flase");
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
False
```

**Code 2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[]="bonaparte";
    
    if(s=="bonaparte")
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Flase");
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
False
```

**Code 3:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    if("bonaparte"=="bonaparte")
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Flase");
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
True
```

So, in #1, we compare the base addresses of `s1` and `s2` and obviously they are going to different, so the output is "False".

In #2, we are comparing the base address of `s` and the base address of the constant string `"bonaparte"` and obviously it is again going to be different, so the output is "False".

However, in #3, we are comparing base addresses of one constant string `"bonaparte"` and another constant string `"bonaparte"`. I think that the string names are same but they will get different locations in memory so, when we are trying to compare their base addresses, they should be different. But output is contradicting to above (what I think).

So what is exactly happening in the 3<sup>rd</sup> case?

Comment: `but they will get different location in memory` _Why_ would the compiler store this (read only) data twice? Would be a waste of space.

Comment: There's probably only one copy of the string literal but you can't count on that. There's a reason `strcmp` and friends exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling your third code sample, the compiler is applying what is often called "string pooling" – that is, the compiler spots that two (or more) string literals are the same and, as such constants cannot be changed at runtime, optimizes the code by generating only one instance of the data, so the two literals end up with the same address.

Most compilers do this by default, but you may be able to disable it. For example, in Visual Studio with the MSVC compiler, you can set the `/GF-` option to disable it. With this set, your code above gives "Flase" (*sic*) as the output ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gf-eliminate-duplicate-strings?view=msvc-160)).

Comment: fist of all thanks, do you have any idea how to disable it in DEV C++

Comment: @AbhishekMane Not entirely sure but, IIRC Dev-C++ uses the GCC compiler internally. If so, the compile option `-fno-merge-constants` may be what you need, and/or with all optimizations turned off.